# How to test for exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin

I'm trying to detect if and instance of IE has been manually closed. The IE instance is actually inside Watin in this example.

```
ie = new IE ();

var ieObj = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass)ie.InternetExplorer;
```

if I close the IE window before the second line of code then ieObj still gets assigned and shows the following in the Locals window

[image]

Is it possible to test ieObj for this possible exception without raising an exception?

For example, I know if I attempt to do anything with the object it will raise an exception eg `var ieBusy = ieObj.Busy;`  but I wanted to know if it was possible to test for this without raising an exception?

Comment: The object reference is still valid but you're talking to a dead parrot on the other end of the line.  You have to subscribe the OnQuit event and stop using the interface when that event fires.

Comment: @Hans Passant - this dead parrot may just be a Norwegian Blue; they stun easy, you know.  (This reference doesn't work if you are not a Monty Python fan.)